# Weathered around her eyes?

Tags: meaning

I'm an Italian trying to read English books and I came upon an expression I can't fully understand.

The word is "weathered". From what I've seen, it means worn out by weather, but this is used about a human face : "a bit weathered around her eyes". Talking about a woman in her late 20s. Does that mean wrinkles? Or sun damaged? Or color deterioration?

Comment: Wrinkles such as [crow's feet](https://www.google.com/search?q=crows+feet&rlz=1C1OPNX_en&oq=crows+feet&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDM1MzFqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), *as though* living through the harshest weather of wind and sea.

Comment: It can be anything negative to do with eyes: circles, bags, fine lines, etc.

Comment: "weathered" = showing the effects of weather. Not "worn out".

Comment: It can also mean weathered by *life*, implied by Yosef Baskin.

Comment: [Weathered](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weathered): "changed in colour or form over a period of time because of the effects of sun, wind, or other weather conditions :
*weathered stone/tiles*.
*His silver hair was cut short around his weathered face.*"

Comment: [*Weathered faces lined in pain*](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Don-McLean/Vincent).

Comment: It's often used figuratively for faces, so it doesn't have to be literally due to weather effects.